# efficient way to read large data from a file in python

Tags: python-3.x, file-read

I have a 10000 files and each file has 2000 samples. Each file is written in a following pattern:

```
discoal 4 2000 55000 -Pt 1750.204699 17502.046985 -Pre 19252.251684 57756.755051
939889312 676473727

###Example 1
//
segsites: 3
positions: 0.000616 0.001428 0.001500
100
001
101
100

###Example 2
segsites: 6
positions: 0.001843 0.002019 0.002102 0.002431 0.003427 0.004103 
000101
101000
001100
110111
```

**Details for file:**

Each file begins with **discoal** and a line with two numbers. These lines are to be ignored. The data needed is **segsites**, **position**, and the binary values that I have after **positions**. Each line (of binary values) would correspond to a row in a matrix.

The number of segsites would correspond to the length of positions vector and the # of columns in binary matrix. For example, in the first example, my segsites is 3 therefore, my position vector would also have 3 values in it. And my binary matrix would be of size 4 x 3. It's '4' because there are four lines of binary values in the example.

My code does all of this. But I want to keep only those examples where segsites is less than 5000.

This is just an example. Otherwise I have segsites upto 10000. I have made a code that goes through all of these files. And for each of these files, it obtains # of segregating sites, positions and puts the binary values below positions into a matrix. Forexample for the first example the matrix would be of size 4 x 3 and second would be 4 x 6.

My code is:

```
def reading_filenames(path_to_directory,extension,tot_segsites,positions,snp_matrix):
    """
    This function returns the file names in the directory of interest
    """

    path = path_to_directory + extension 
    files = glob.glob(path)

    i=0
    for file in files:     
        f=open(file, 'r')  
        #print('file : ',file)
        reading_file(f.readlines(),tot_segsites,positions,snp_matrix,i)
        i += 1

        f.close() 

    return files, snp_matrix

    #return [f for f in os.listdir(path_to_directory) if f.endswith(extension)]

def reading_file(file,tot_segsites,positions,snp_matrix,i):

    flag = False
    length = 0
    counter = 0
    array = np.zeros((chrm_num,6000))
    for line in file:
        if 'segsites:' in line:
            lst = (line.strip('\n').split(': '))
            res = int(lst[1])
            tot_segsites.append(res)

        elif 'position' in line:
            lst = line.strip('\n').split(': ')
            lst = lst[1:]
            res = [float(k) for k in lst[0].split(' ')]

            for j in range(len(res)):
                positions[i][j] = res[j]

            flag = True

        elif flag:
            lst = line.strip('\n')
            reading_snp_matrix(lst,length,chrm_num,counter,array)
            counter += 1
            flag = True

    snp_matrix.append((array))
    return snp_matrix

def reading_snp_matrix(line,length,chrm_num,counter,array):
    chromosome = list(map(int, line))
    for i in range(len(chromosome)):
        array[counter][i] = chromosome[i]
```

**reading_filenames** function simply reads the files in the folder and for each file it calls the function **reading_file**. And **reading_file** function then reads segsites, positions and the binary matrix. However, I want to change this code so that only those segsites, positions and binary matrix are stored whose segsites is 5000 or less but not more. I don't know how to achieve that with the code I've made. 
Also, can you tell me an efficient way to read the file in the format I've mentioned. Because this code is quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can read your file, convert it to csv, write it again (once). Then you can use `pandas` to read csv and manipulate it easily

Comment: But if instead of converting it to csv how can I take care of the fact that only those segsites, positions and binary matrix is stored whose segsites is less or equal to 5000.

Comment: You cannot benifit from it. Because the count of "segsites" can only be knwon after reading the whole file (If I understand correctly)

Comment: So once I read the segsites, I know what the corresponding length of positions vector would and # of columns of binary matrix. Segsites would change within the file as well. Each sample has it's own segsites. For example, my first example has 3 segsites and second has 6 segsites.

Comment: Because converting this file format in csv format wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Please give me more details. I don't know "segsites" or your file structure

Comment: I added details. Check ''details for file"

Comment: If I were you, I would convert to csv first. Then filter that csv with your 5000 condition. Then write a 2nd csv with the filtered data for usage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192047/discussion-between-shafa-haider-and-findoutislamnow).